# iOS app with Custom Tabbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, custom-controls

I am using a custom tabbar. Related to this I have a question regarding the *iOS Human Interface Guidelines*.

First I will state something about my app development process. In my custom tabbar, for example: if I select `Settings`, it will move to the `settings view`, but in that `settings view` there won't be `Custom tabbar`. Instead, there will be a `back` button. Like this, it'll be the same for the remaining tabs also.

Because of this, is there a problem while submitting the app to the [App Store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Store_%28iOS%29)? Based on *iOS Human Interface Guidelines*, as far as I checked, there isn't any problem.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's OK. No problem with that. I already added an app like this. Please check this one:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photomatrix/id645791639?ls=1&mt=8

I added the gallery like you said (without any tab bar).

Comment: wow.great thanks.good App.but i have done for all tabs.default Tab selected will be as `Home`.other than that if you select `Map` or `Settings` , it'll lead to another view without Tabs. is this OK?

Comment: yeah its ok.no problem with that. All the best. Can u pls post a good comment for my app.